# assign a value to the textbox for login panel in ACCESS

Tags: ms-access

I have a table contains usernames and passwords and i want to create login panel with two textboxes(username and password). How can i check the values in textbox with the all users and passwords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA you can test:

```vb
Dim count As Long

count = DCount("*", "tblUser", "UserName='" & Replace(Me!txtUser,"'","''") & _
    "' AND Password='" & Replace(Me!txtPwd, "'", "''") & "'")
If count > 0 Then
    'User exists and password is correct.
Else
    'Either the user or the password or both are wrong.
End If
```

The replace functions make sure that single quotes (`'`) that are part of the user input are escaped correctly. In SQL single quotes are used to delimit strings and a quote within the text can be escaped with two consequtive quotes.

As an example, the where condition could be:

```sql
UserName='Joe''s friend' AND Password='secret'
```